# Shell Script Invocation Error: no such file or directory in xcode 8 with swift 3

Tags: ios, shell, afnetworking, swift3, xcode8

[image]

When I compile my code, Shell Script Invocation error happen in my project.
I did Clean->Build->Restart my project. But it didn't help.
I did again Clean DerivedData, but still the same error.
How to solve this error. Please help me.

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Comment: Yes! I delete podfile and reinstall ! That's solved @CheshireKat

Comment: Did you have to delete the .workspace file also? Deleting the pods and reinstalling didn't work for me. I'm still seeing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create scheme of the selected pod, choose it and run build. After include framework of the selected pod.